# GraphQL - Is it possible to set a variable with a result for a mutation

Tags: graphql

I want to do 2 creations in my GraphQL query. (I know my query structure is not correct, but it's to illustrate my question)

```
mutation {
    affiliateCreate(company: "test mutation") {
    $id: id,
    affiliateUserCreate(affiliate_id: $id, name: "test name") {
      id, 
      name
    },
    company
  }
}
```

I want my first id result to be in variable who i pass to the second creation call? I'm very new to GraphQL and i was wondering if it's possible.

Is there any other way possible to do such thing? Or i must do 2 mutation call? The first with `affiliateCreate` and in it's fallback the second one?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is not supported by GraphQL. In the Graphcool APIs we approach this kind of situation with what we call *nested mutations*. I've also heard it being referred to as *complex mutations*.

A nested create mutation is characterized by a nested *input object argument*. If you add an input object `author` to the `affiliateCreate` mutation, you could use it like that:

```
mutation createAffiliateAndUser {
  affiliateCreate(
    company: "test company"
    author: {
      name: "test user"
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

This would create an affiliate, a user and then link the two together. Similarily, if you add an input object `affiliates` to the `userCreate` mutation, it could look like this:

```
mutation createUserAndAffiliates {
  userCreate(
    name: "test user"
    affiliates: [{
      company: "first company"
    }, {
      company: "second company"
    }]
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess, in your callback of the resolve method, you pass the user id to create the affiliates?

Comment: Sadly, the [link](https://www.graph.cool/blog/improving-dx-with-nested-mutations-vietahx7ih/) is dead. :-) Searching for the phrase "improving dx with nested mutations" just turned up links to the dead link.