# graphql multiple mutations using prior mutation return results?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I understand that mutations are sequential, so it makes sense to me that if Mutation 1 creates an entity and returns an id, that Mutation 2 should have access to that id. However I don't see any examples online and can't seem to get it to work. I see that people say you need to handle this in the resolve function of your route but it seems like extra unnecessary code if I can get this in just the query.

For example I have the following where accounts belong to clients and hence need the clientId before being created. However this does not work...

```
mutation createClientAndAccount($account: AccountInput, $client: ClientInput){
      createClient(client: $client){ clientId }
      createAccount(account: $account, clientId: USE_CLIENT_ID_FROM_ABOVE) { ... } 
    }
```

I've also tried nesting mutations but didn't have much luck there either...

Is what i'm trying to do possible? Would the resolve function of `createAccount` have the return data from `createClient`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL - Is it possible to set a variable with a result for a mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377518/graphql-is-it-possible-to-set-a-variable-with-a-result-for-a-mutation)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible right now, though would be useful.
See [this PR](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462).

Comment: Couple years down the line, and here is a discussion in official GraphQL repo: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/583 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a [custom schema directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/) we could achieve that.

[Schema stitching](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/graphql-schema-stitching/) will be a better approach(though usually it is preferred in API Gateway for merging APIs from different services).

If this requirement is very rare in your application, simply creating a new API that can do both `CreateClientAndAccount` is enough.