# In GraphQL, Can I get passed parameters in next query from previous query when using multiple mutation in one request

Tags: graphql

I'm sorry for that title is so long. 
I have a question about multiple query in one request

Assume that you should upload one picture and its title.
so you could use two mutations in one request like under example.

(explicit mutation)

1. uploadPicture(File) : String
2. uploadPictureTitle(String) : String

so I wonder if after getting first URL from uploading picture to storage, i  could get URL from first mutation and update title and URL in my database.

I'm looking forward to taking good advice. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [graphql multiple mutations using prior mutation return results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441566/graphql-multiple-mutations-using-prior-mutation-return-results)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank You!